# Python: Group same integer values, then average

Tags: python

I have a huge array of data and I would like to do subgroups for the values for same integers and then take their average.

For example:

```
a = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
```

I want to take sub groups as follows:

```
[0, 0.5] [1, 1.5] [2, 2.5]
```

... and then take the average and put all the averages in a new array.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by "take the average"? please provide an example of valid input and expected output.

Comment: Also explain the logic of the sub-groups. Is it all floats between 2 integers?

Comment: Yes Tomerikoo, it means the floats between 2 integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to group by the number's integer value (so the number rounded down), something like this could work:

```
>>> a = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
>>> groups = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(a, int)]
>>> groups
[[0, 0.5], [1, 1.5], [2, 2.5]]
```

Then averaging becomes:

```
>>> [sum(grp) / len(grp) for grp in groups]
[0.25, 1.25, 2.25]
```

This assumes `a` is already sorted, as in your example.

Ref: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: If it’s not sorted: `groups = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(a), int)]`

Comment: And it might be faster to use [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) instead of doing it yourself with `sum` and `len`

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problem using additional libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
print(pd.Series(a).groupby(np.array(a, dtype=np.int32)).mean())
```

Gives:

```
0    0.25
1    1.25
2    2.25
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to easily get that (you might need to sort the list first):

```py
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

a = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
for k, group in groupby(a, key=int):
    print(mean(group))
```

Will give:

```
0.25
1.25
2.25
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an approach with dictionary, you can go ahead like this:

```
dic={}
a = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
for items in a:
    if int(items) not in dic:
        dic[int(items)]=[]
    dic[int(items)].append(items)
print(dic)

for items in dic:
    dic[items]=sum(dic[items])/len(dic[items])
print(dic)
```